# Kubernetes EndPointSlice for service without selector

Tags: kubernetes, endpoint

I cannot solve this problem.

Kubernetes version: **1.23.1**

My cluster is divided into three zones:

- zone1
- zone2
- zone3

There are three mysql databases. They are not in kubernetes

- 192.168.0.101
- 192.168.0.102
- 192.168.0.103

I made a service for them without selectors.

And added endpointslice. But I get connection refused. Please tell me what I did wrong, thanks.

To test it, I made 3 pods with a mysql client, which, depending on the zone, should go to the required database.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-mysql
  annotations:
    service.kubernetes.io/topology-aware-hints: auto
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306

---

apiVersion: discovery.k8s.io/v1
kind: EndpointSlice
metadata:
  name: test-mysql
  annotations:
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/service-name: test-mysql
addressType: IPv4
ports:
 - name: mysql
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3306
endpoints:
 - addresses:
      - "192.168.0.101"
    conditions:
      ready: true
    zone: zone1
    hints:
      forZones:
        - name: "zone1"
 - addresses:
      - "192.168.0.102"
    conditions:
      ready: true
    zone: zone2
    hints:
      forZones:
        - name: "zone2"
 - addresses:
      - "192.168.0.103"
    conditions:
      ready: true
    zone: zone3
    hints:
      forZones:
        - name: "zone3"
```

Nginx just for testing, I put mysql-client on it

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - web-store
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Labels nodes:

```
kubectl label nodes node1 node2 topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone1
kubectl label nodes node1 node2 kubernetes.io/zone=zone1
```

Comment: How do you reckon the service will know about the endpoint slice it represents. without a selector?

Comment: @CloudBalancing https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors

Answer (score 0):

**TopologyAwareHints available since 1.24**

**For 1.23 you need to enable --feature-gates=TopologyAwareHints=true**

[https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/#:~:text=1.23-,TopologyAwareHints,-true](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/#:%7E:text=1.23-,TopologyAwareHints,-true)

**Simple example:**

Label nodes:

```
kubectl label nodes $NODE_ZONE_1 topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone1
kubectl label nodes $NODE_ZONE_2 topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone2
kubectl label nodes $NODE_ZONE_3 topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone3
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: galera
  annotations:
    service.kubernetes.io/topology-aware-hints: auto
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      name: mysql
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3306
---
apiVersion: discovery.k8s.io/v1
kind: EndpointSlice
metadata:
  name: galera-ep
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/service-name: galera
addressType: IPv4
ports:
  - name: mysql
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3306
endpoints:
  - addresses:
      - "192.168.0.11"
    conditions:
      ready: true
    zone: zone1
    hints:
      forZones:
       - name: "zone1"
  - addresses:
      - "192.168.0.12"
    conditions:
      ready: true
      serving: true
    zone: zone2
    hints:
      forZones:
        - name: "zone2"
  - addresses:
      - "192.168.0.13"
    conditions:
      ready: true
      serving: true
    zone: zone3
    hints:
      forZones:
        - name: "zone3"
```

Deploy:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ubuntu
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ubuntu
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ubuntu
    spec:
      topologySpreadConstraints:
      - maxSkew: 1
        topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
        whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
        labelSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: ubuntu
      containers:
      - name: ubuntu
        args:
        - while true; do sleep 1000; done;
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - --
        image: ubuntu:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Inside pod:

> If in one namespace

```
mysql -p -h galera.svc -P 3306
```

> If in different namespaces

```
mysql -p -h galera.svc.default.cluster.local -P 3306
```